# Translating a pager string

Tags: pagination, translation

Most of Wordpress function found in themes look like this:

```
<?php echo get_next_posts_link( 'Older posts', $the_query->max_num_pages ); // display older posts link ?>

<?php echo get_previous_posts_link( 'Newer posts' ); // display newer posts link ?>
```

This works as expected.

However, how can I rewrite this in order to translate it?

I tried:

```
<?php _e( echo get_next_posts_link( 'Older posts', $the_query->max_num_pages ); ) ?>
```

But this does not seem to work. Maybe this is not the proper way to translate a pager.

Any help is welcome.

Regards,

Johann

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong

- You should translate the HTML string, not the function
- When passing strings into functions, like what you are doing, you should use `__()` which returns the translated string. `_e()` would echo the string and you would get the raw text and the modified text on output

  Example of correct usage:

  ```
  get_next_posts_link( __( 'Older posts' ), $the_query->max_num_pages );
  ```

  or

  ```
  next_posts_link( __( 'Older posts' ), $the_query->max_num_pages );
  ```
- `_e()` echos a string, so doing the following

  ```
  next_posts_link( _e( 'Older posts' ), $the_query->max_num_pages );
  ```

  would be wrong as you would get the following output

  > Older postsNext Page »

  instead of

  > Older posts
- Instead of doing `echo get_next_posts_link()`, you can just do `next_posts_link()`. `next_posts_link()` is just a wrapper for `echo get_next_posts_link()`